# How to change a string value of an activity from php script and recreate a apk file

Tags: php, android, apk

I want to change the value of a string variable of an activity with php script and want to recreate the apk file to reflect the changes. How can i do that?

I have an apk that has a unique id(id generate at web server upon registration). this id will be different for every installation.
Now i want create a php script that will hard code this id in my activity file.
But the question is how i will build apk file from php end. is there any way?

Comment: Please elaborate, for now it is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: A little more explanation with code will be helpful to solve your question. Can you post your code until you have tried?

Comment: Please check the edits

Comment: I have found the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918154/change-apk-asset-file-from-outside

Comment: Upon installation of apk you have to give new ID right?

Comment: But no answer to solve the problem.

Comment: yes.Right, Upon installation of apk i have to give new ID

Comment: How you are identifying whether it's a new user or not then assigning the registration Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually compile & build then sign the apk with new ID. There are other ways to give registration id for an apk. You have to store unique id of android device & map the registration id with that apk from server side.

1. Create a new registration Id in server & store it in database.
2. On first startup of your application you have to pass the device id or other unique id from android to server.
3. Next step is to map the device id with registration id & store it in database.
4. Mostly you will be doing this while login (can identify the user).
5. For local operation you can store it in SQLite database also.

Comment: is there no way to automatize the change of a file and compile/sign after the apk, from outside?

Comment: Then you might depend upon some external file. Store the Id in a file passing from server then read.

Comment: @user3759273 How you are identifying whether it's a new user or not then assigning the registration Id?